# Camera not opening in iPad objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am able to select pics on iPhone using camera as well as photo library. However, the same thing is not working on iPad. Read couple of tutorials but I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;

-(void)captureImage:(NSInteger)sourceType{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [self cameraUsingiPad];
        return;
    }
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera Unavailable" message:@"Unable to find a camera on your device." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    alert = nil;
}
```

}

```
-(void) cameraUsingiPad {
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Camera is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10 and 11, user have to allow using camera.
So, you should add the description in info.plist.

[image]

Comment: This is already there. That is the reason I am able to click pics using an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Permissions. Fixed that.

Comment: Hi, may I know what is the permission that you have fixed? We have the exact issue...